# Failed compile vlc android recipe for target '.a52' failed

Tags: android, ubuntu, compilation, vlc

I follow all the steps on https://wiki.videolan.org/AndroidCompile/ but when I do the sh compile.sh -a armeabi-v7a at the end I have this error:

> checking for arm-linux-androideabi-gcc... arm-linux-androideabi-gcc --sysroot=/home/yann/android-ndk-r11c/platforms/android-9/arch-arm
>   checking whether the C compiler works... no
>   configure: error: in `/home/yann/vlc-android/vlc/contrib/contrib-android-arm-linux-androideabi/a52dec':
>   configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
>   See`config.log' for more details
>   ../../contrib/src/a52/rules.mak:26: recipe for target '.a52' failed
>   make: *** [.a52] Error 77
>   contribs: make failed

I am working on vm ubuntu 16.04 x32

Comment: Take a look at http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/146402/configure-error-c-compiler-cannot-create-executables

Comment: Solved by using vm ubuntu 16.04 x64.

Comment: not solved, tried everything